# the trait `std::clone::Clone` is not implemented for `Nominations<T>`

Tags: substrate-node-template, rust, events, substrateinterface, pallet-staking

I was making a new event in the function nominate of Staking pallet which is going to show when the nominator is going to be added. But i facing one issue

```
#[pallet::call_index(5)]
    #[pallet::weight(T::WeightInfo::nominate(targets.len() as u32))]
    pub fn nominate(
        origin: OriginFor<T>,
        targets: Vec<AccountIdLookupOf<T>>,
    ) -> DispatchResult {
        let controller = ensure_signed(origin)?;

        let ledger = Self::ledger(&controller).ok_or(Error::<T>::NotController)?;
        ensure!(ledger.active >= MinNominatorBond::<T>::get(), Error::<T>::InsufficientBond);
        let stash = &ledger.stash;

        // Only check limits if they are not already a nominator.
        if !Nominators::<T>::contains_key(stash) {
            // If this error is reached, we need to adjust the `MinNominatorBond` and start
            // calling `chill_other`. Until then, we explicitly block new nominators to protect
            // the runtime.
            if let Some(max_nominators) = MaxNominatorsCount::<T>::get() {
                ensure!(
                    Nominators::<T>::count() < max_nominators,
                    Error::<T>::TooManyNominators
                );
            }
        }

        ensure!(!targets.is_empty(), Error::<T>::EmptyTargets);
        ensure!(targets.len() <= T::MaxNominations::get() as usize, Error::<T>::TooManyTargets);

        let old = Nominators::<T>::get(stash).map_or_else(Vec::new, |x| x.targets.into_inner());

        let targets: BoundedVec<_, _> = targets
            .into_iter()
            .map(|t| T::Lookup::lookup(t).map_err(DispatchError::from))
            .map(|n| {
                n.and_then(|n| {
                    if old.contains(&n) || !Validators::<T>::get(&n).blocked {
                        Ok(n)
                    } else {
                        Err(Error::<T>::BadTarget.into())
                    }
                })
            })
            .collect::<Result<Vec<_>, _>>()?
            .try_into()
            .map_err(|_| Error::<T>::TooManyNominators)?;

        let nominations = Nominations {
            targets,
            // Initial nominations are considered submitted at era 0. See `Nominations` doc.
            submitted_in: Self::current_era().unwrap_or(0),
            suppressed: false,
        };

        //let put = &nominations.put;

        Self::do_remove_validator(stash);
        Self::do_add_nominator(stash, nominations);
        Self::deposit_event(Event::<T>::NominatorSet { stash: ledger.stash, nominations });

        Ok(())
    }
```

and in  Event

```
#[pallet::event]
#[pallet::generate_deposit(pub(crate) fn deposit_event)]
pub enum Event<T: Config> {
  NominatorSet{stash: T::AccountId, nominations: Nominations<T>},
}
```

and it is this error
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change `Clone` in derive above `Nominations` to `CloneNoBound`. The difference between `Clone` and `CloneNoBound` is the handling of `T`. In case of `Clone` it adds the bound `Clone` to `T`. `CloneNoBound` doesn't add this bound. The bound to `Clone` is wrong you don't need that `T` implements `Clone`, you only require that some of the associated types implement `Clone`.